# typescript make a simple d.ts file for npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to declare a .d.ts file to use [npm uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) in an agular 2 app. What I'm doing seems to be in line with the example I found, yet I get the error : `typescript d.ts file has no exported members v1`

**uuid/v1.d.ts file:**

```
declare var v1: any;

declare module "uuid/v1" {
    export = v1;
}
```

the npm js file is **uuid/v1.js**:

```
function v1(options, buf, offset) { //...}

module.exports = v1;
```

I also tried :

```
export = uuid;
declare namespace uuid {
  function v1(): any;
}
```

which gives a runtime exception:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function
```

Comment: How are your importing it?

Comment: @AluanHaddad like this `import { v1 } from 'uuid/v1';`

Comment: You need to export the function from the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this will be similar to how I wrote a DefinitelyTyped file. See [@types/selenium-webdriver](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts).

```
declare namespace uuid {
  interface V1Options {
    /**
     * Node id as Array of 6 bytes (per 4.1.6).
     * Default: Randomly generated ID.
     */
    node?: Array<any>;
    /**
     * Number between 0 - 0x3fff. RFC clock sequence.
     * Default: An internally maintained clockseq is used
     */
    clockseq?: number;
    /**
     * Time in milliseconds since unix Epoch.
     * Default: The current time is used.
     */
    msecs: number|Date;
    /**
     * Number between 0-9999) additional time, in 100-nanosecond units.
     * Ignored if msecs is unspecified. Default: internal uuid
     * counter is used, as per 4.2.1.2.
     */
    nsecs: number;
  };

  /**
   * Generate and return a RFC4122 v1 (timestamp-based) UUID.
   * @param {V1Options} options Optional uuid state to apply.
   * @param {Array<any>|Buffer} buffer Array or buffer where
   *        UUID bytes are to be written.
   * @param {number} offset Starting index in buffer at which to begin writing.
   */
  v1(options?: V1Options, buffer?: Array<any>|Buffer, offset?: number): Buffer;
}
export = uuid;
```

I believe you'll have to direct your `tsconfig.json` to use this file (or get it published to DefinitelyTyped) and then you can `import {v1, V1Options} from 'uuid';` or `import * from 'uuid';`

Comment: There is a couple errors there. after fixing those there is still an error at runtime.

Comment: Do you have this in a github repo? I'll take a look at it this weekend.